# Web service architecture design

Tags: web-services, api, architecture

I am aiming to create some API or service which's output must be shown on the website and that needs to access the database of the client. But the code should be on my server thus service.

I thought it liked this, when a page request happens the client lets my server know about the request and it's type. Then my server queries the clients database (which is remote from MY server) and gets the data needed to run the algorithm. Then the algorithm is run and the output is returned to the clients server which is then processed again (adding html tags etc) and shown to the user.

Is this a sane architecture? The output to be shown is not the actual value of the page, I mean it's only like an add-on. So asynchronous loading also wouldn't hurt. I believe in a synchronous manner this will heavily slow the page loading times.

How would you accomplish this kind of task if (your code needs to stay private && client database and your server are remotely connected && output of your code affects the page) :))

The last one is meaning it's not just enough that client sends you some data, it is also interested in the output.

*PS: I feel that this kind of question isn't very much liked in SO. But I sometimes have this kind of questions and SO is the real deal where you can get the fastest and mostly exceptional answers. If this needs to be closed, can someone point in a comment where we can discuss such questions on web?*

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic of some depth, and so this is probably not the correct place to go into a lot of detail. Basically, you need to understand asynchronous Javascript/ajax calls. This is  usually made quite straight forward through many of the popular Javascript frameworks, and so that is where I recommend you look next.